# Passing an operator as a function

Tags: groovy, syntax

I am new to Groovy. I would like to pass an operator as a function.

Instead of:

```
nums.inject(0) { acc, el -> acc * el }
```

I would like to do something like:

```
nums.inject(0) {*}
```

In F#, this is possible. Does Groovy offer the same syntactic sugar?

```
let product = List.reduce (*) nums 0
```

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible in groovy.

Comment: I don't believe it does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators are not allowed to be passed around but functions/closures are, so more or less equivalent

`def product = nums.inject(1, Math.&multiplyExact)`

`inject` takes two arguments, an object and a closure. Your example defines its own closure but it's possible to reference methods as closures using the [method pointer operator (.&)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#method-pointer-operator)

Putting a *literal* closure, the `{ }`, outside the parenthesis is a little syntactic sugar that can be done for any closure that is a method call's last argument.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. But, you can get close with some meta programming.

```
/* 
 * Creates the method Collection.reduce(Object, Closure).
 * Unlike Collection.inject(Object, Closure), this method
 * expects a closure with a single argument: the
 * current element in the collection. The closure is
 * re-created to run with the accumulated value as the
 * owner and then called with the current element as the argument.
 */
Collection.metaClass.reduce = { Object initial, Closure closure ->
    delegate.inject(initial) { acc, obj ->
        closure.rehydrate(acc, acc, acc)(obj)
    }
}

def nums = [1, 2, 3]

/*
 * Number.&multiply returns the Number.multiply(Number) method
 * as a Closure.
 */
def result = nums.reduce(1, Number.&multiply) 

assert result == 6
```

To give you an better idea of how the `reduce(Object, Closure)` method works, there's another way to use it:

```
nums.reduce(1) { num -> multiply(num) }
```

The closure's only argument is the current element. Because all method calls and property accesses are delegated to the accumulator, the `multiply(Number)` method executes against the accumulator: `acc.multiply(num)`.